# "Отображать поверх экрана блокировки" при запуске приложения направить пользователя в настройки, чтобы он дал разрешение (Андроид)

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

Как предоставить разрешение на отображение поверх экрана блокировки, и через кнопку направить пользователя в настройки?

[image: Вот так выглядит в настройках]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете перейти в настройки приложения например таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

вот есть [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android), может пригодится.